# How to define all socket.io logic outside of app.js in a separate-file Express.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

**Desired Behaviour**

The [socket.io initialisation docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/#es-modules) provides this example, which I currently use in `app.js`:

```js
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // ...
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

I also have three objects before the `io` block that need to be referenced from within the block:

```js
var logged_in_users = {};
var users_in_rooms = {};
var live_edits_occurring = {};
```

As you can see, everything happens in `app.js`.

I want to refactor `app.js` so that:

1. All logic in the `io.on('connection')` function block is outside of `app.js`
2. The global objects (`logged_in_users` etc) are accessible in middleware files

**Actual Behaviour**

I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: logged_in_users is not defined

which means I cannot access `logged_in_users` from a middleware file.

**Question**

How can I get the objects like `logged_in_users` to be globally accessible?

So that they can be referenced *and updated* by all the middleware files?

Would [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals) be a good approach?

```js
// app.js  
app.locals.logged_in_users = {};
app.locals.users_in_rooms = {};
app.locals.live_edits_occurring = {};
```

I haven't used `app.locals` before and I wouldn't know how to access `app` within the middleware.

I also don't know if you can update `app.locals` from middleware, which I would need to do.

**What I've Tried**

Following [the docs on application structure](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-application-structure), I have:

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);


const all_socketio_logic = require('./middleware/socketio/all_socketio_logic').all_socketio_logic;    
  
const on_connection = async (socket) => {
  all_socketio_logic(io, socket);
};

io.on('connection', on_connection);
```

**/middleware/socketio/all_socketio_logic.js**

```js
import { heres_my_details } from './event_handler_heres_my_details';

const all_socketio_logic = (io, socket) => {

  // i want these available in the middleware defined below     
  var logged_in_users = {};
  var users_in_rooms = {};
  var live_edits_occurring = {};

  // sanity checks - all returning values - GOOD   
  console.log('socket.id is: ' + socket.id);
  console.log('logged_in_users is: ');
  console.log(logged_in_users);
  console.log('users_in_rooms is: ');
  console.log(users_in_rooms);
  console.log('live_edits_occurring is: ');
  console.log(live_edits_occurring);

  // this is being returned to browser - GOOD 
  socket.emit('heres_your_socket_id', socket.id);  

  // this middleware is running - GOOD  
  socket.on('heres_my_details', heres_my_details);

  /*

  i will add other event handlers here:  
  
  socket.on('another_event_01', another_event_01);
  socket.on('another_event_02', another_event_02);

  etc  

  */

};

export { all_socketio_logic };
```

**/middleware/socketio/event_handler_heres_my_details.js**

```js
const heres_my_details = (data) => {
  
  console.log('heres_my_details:');
  console.log(data);
  
  var username = data.username;
  
  // if client is logged in
  if (username !== null) {
    var user_email = data.user_email;
  
    /* 
      if the logged_in_users object doesn't already contain 
      the clients socket id (as a property), add the socket 
      id property and define object username and user_email 
    */
  
    if (!logged_in_users.hasOwnProperty(socket.id)) {
      // the error is here - cannot access logged_in_users  
      logged_in_users[socket.id] = {};   
      logged_in_users[socket.id].username = username;
      logged_in_users[socket.id].user_email = user_email;
      console.log('logged_in_users AFTER ADDING new object:');
      console.log(logged_in_users);
    }
  }
};

export { heres_my_details };
```

I get the following logged - GOOD:

```
socket.id is: zhWMY0EpkNAWURN3AAAB
logged_in_users is:
{}
users_in_rooms is:
{}
live_edits_occurring is:
{}
heres_my_details:
{
  username: 'my username',
  user_email: 'my@email_address.com',
  logged_in: true
}
```

Error from `event_handler_heres_my_details.js` - BAD:

> ReferenceError: logged_in_users is not defined

**Similar questions** *(with outdated or incomplete answers)*

[Use socket.io in expressjs routes instead of in main server.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837685/use-socket-io-in-expressjs-routes-instead-of-in-main-server-js-file)

[Node.js how to use socket.io in express route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405137/node-js-how-to-use-socket-io-in-express-route)

[Using socket.io with express 4 generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016350/using-socket-io-with-express-4-generator)

[NodeJS socket.io in a router page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249009/nodejs-socket-io-in-a-router-page/47252201)

[Separating socket.io logic from app.js in feathersjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716602/separating-socket-io-logic-from-app-js-in-feathersjs)

[How to move Socket.io io.on('connection') code another js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517979/how-to-move-socket-io-io-onconnection-code-another-js-file)

[Separate Socket.io into app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053199/separate-socket-io-into-app-js)

[Separating file server and socket.io logic in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709912/separating-file-server-and-socket-io-logic-in-node-js)

**Environment**

node v16.13.0
express: ^4.17.1
socket.io: ^4.3.2
socket.io-client: ^4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

appp.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = require('./ws.js')(httpServer);
```

ws.js

```
module.exports = function ws(httpServer) {

    var logged_in_users = {};
    var users_in_rooms = {};
    var live_edits_occurring = {}; 

    const { Server } = require('socket.io');
    const io = new Server(httpServer);

    httpServer.use(function(req, res, next){
        // attach io, etc. to every req object
        req.ws = {
            io,
            logged_in_users,
            users_in_rooms,
            live_edits_occurring
        };
        // call next to pass req to handler
        next();
    });
    
    io.on('connection', on_connection);

};
```

Comment: I'm curious. What version of Node are you using that allows you to pass additional arguments to `require('path', ...)`? Because I'm pretty sure `const io = require('./ws.js', httpServer);` isn't doing what you hope it will. ;)

Comment: @RobRaisch sure, my bad, it should be `const io = require('./ws.js')(httpServer);` Thanks for pointing that out.